# I'm trying to add an external contact in mysql, but I get an error

Tags: mysql

Error:
mysql> INSERT INTO mysql.user (host, user, password) VALUES ('%','root', password('1234'));
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'

Comment: Put your table structure and your query as well.

Comment: as error says...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clearly stated:

```
Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'
```

check if `mysql.user` has the password column or not by making an select query.